# OpenLayers restrictedExtent does not restrict while zooming

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have downloaded Amsterdam map as tiles and I try and load with the code below. The problem is that when I am zooming in the web page is filled up with the downloaded map and is no problem but when I zoom out my map becomes really small and the web page is filled with pink tiles. Please help

My javacode is as under

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds("-20037508.3427892,
                                                  -20037508.3427892,
                                                  20037508.3427892,
                                                  20037508.3427892"),          
                restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds("-20037508.3427892,
                                                  -20037508.3427892,
                                                  20037508.3427892,
                                                  20037508.3427892"),  
                minzoomlevel: 10,
                numZoomLevels: 17,
                projection: "EPSG:900913",
                displayProjection: "EPSG:4326"} );

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
      "New Layer", 
      "http://localhost/WebClient/Openstreetmap/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you got these insane large numbers and why are they all the same? You are supposed to add valid lat and long values there. See the [restricted extent example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/restricted-extent.html).

Comment: These are in EPSG:900913. I also tried to use 4.8556,52.3507,4.9629,52.3861 but its the same result

Comment: Still you are passing always same numbers but you are supposed to pass different numbers in order to create a bounding box. Does restrictedExtent work when passing coordinates in EPSG:4326?

Comment: Tried with EPSG:4326 and it works. Transform to EPSG:900913 is required though.

Comment: The link shared in the answer is dead. Could you please explain if possible?

Comment: @andex Thanks for the hint, I updated the link. This example and various others are easy to find when searching for OpenLayers restricted extent.

Comment: Thank you for the update. That link loads but it come up with a blank map. I tried it on Firefox 38.0.5 and Chrome 43.0. However, I used the source and applied but it is not working. By default, I think openlayers uses EPSG:900913 so, I tried, with those long numbers, and with EPSG:4326 too but doesn't work. Some how, I think I have a projection issue.